# Заменить GET параметр на другой

Tags: php, get

```
<a href="<?=(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'id') === false ? '?id=1' : preg_replace("#&id=.*#", '&id=1', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) ?>">Ссылка 1</a>

<a href="<?=(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'id') === false ? '?id=2' : preg_replace("#&id=.*#", '&id=2', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) ?>">Ссылка 2</a>
```

Здравствуйте, код выше работает **но только по клику на первую ссылку**, когда я хочу заменить `GET` параметр по клику на вторую ссылку ниче не происходит, подскажите из за чего это может быть?

Делаю по другому:

```
function GetQuery($val, $paramName)
{

$label = strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?') === false ? '?' : '&';
$query = $_GET[$paramName];

if (isset($query)) {
   $n = preg_replace("#&id=.*&#", '&id=newvalue&', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   print $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $n;
} else {
   $query = $label . $paramName . '=' . $val;
   print $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $query;
   }
}

<a href="<?php GetQuery("1", "id");?>">Ссылка 1</a></li>
```

Если я вывожу принтом простую строку тогда работает, а если то что выше то `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . $n;` добавляется в конец строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, каким способом хотите добиться результата: 1м или 2м.

Если все же правильно понял, то было не корректно составлено регулярное выражение. Замените код на:

```
<a href="<?=(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'id') === false ? '?id=1' : preg_replace("#(\?id\=.*)#", '?id=1', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) ?>">Ссылка 1</a>

<a href="<?=(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'id') === false ? '?id=2' : preg_replace("#(\?id\=.*)#", '?id=2', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) ?>">Ссылка 2</a>
```

Так же рекомендую пользоваться какими-либо онлайн сервисами для проверки регулярных выражений, [например](https://regex101.com/).